# How to solve: Bus error on ubuntu 20.04 with Docker

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I have Ubuntu server 20.04.02 LTS with Docker installed on Intel NUC 8i5BEK. I tried to export docker image by command `sudo docker save -o /my_folder/my_image.tar image1`

docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:           19.03.13
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        xxx
 Built:             Fri Feb  5 15:56:39 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.13
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       xxx
  Built:            Fri Feb  5 15:58:24 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.3.7
  GitCommit:        xxx
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        xxx
```

And I get this error:

```
Bus error

Message from syslogd@srv4 at May 30 19:07:35 ...
 kernel:[19746.597409] systemd[1]: Caught <BUS>, core dump failed (child 12967, code=killed, status=7/BUS).

Message from syslogd@srv4 at May 30 19:07:35 ...
 kernel:[19746.597419] systemd[1]: Freezing execution.
```

What kind of problem is it and how can I solve it?